# Error with rafalib package nullplot() function in R for Range data: error in plot.new

Tags: r, plot, iranges

I'm trying to run the following piece of code on Posit Cloud, testing visualization for some dummy IRange Data:

```
#Define Ranges by start/end
rng3 <- IRanges(start=c(4, 7, 2, 20), end=c(13, 7, 2, 23))

# Plot ranges as lines
nullplot(start(range(rng3)), end(range(rng3))+1, 0, 6, xaxt="n")
abline(v=100:115, col="grey")
axis(1, at=100:115 + .5, labels=100:115) 
arrows(start(rng3),seq_along(rng3),end(rng3)+1,seq_along(rng3),
       lwd=3,code=3,angle=90,length=.05)
```

On my one computer, the code runs fine, but on another, I'm getting the following error from the nullplot() line:

```
Error in plot.new :
could not open file "/home/r2194989/.rstudio/sessions/active/session-5aa67a31/unsaved-notebooks/FDDD2555/1/cluic5rz241hv_t/_rs_chunk_plot_005.png'
```

Additional Information:

- Yes, I'm aware there is a way to visualize range data in ggplot, I'm comparing the two ways of visualization, so I can't just use another way
- I'm absolutely sure that all the packages and libraries are the same on both computers. I even reinstalled them on the computer that's throwing errors just to make sure